# UML class diagram with fixed value in inherited field

Tags: java, ruby, inheritance, uml

I am creating a representation of Java projects in Ruby to calculate some metrics. I am creating Ruby classes for the language elements available in Java (`JavaClass`, `JavaInterface`, `JavaMethod`, etc.). I am drawing a UML class diagram of the Ruby-classes and their relations (`JavaClass contains 0..* JavaMethods`).

I do not know how to represent the following in UML:

- A `JavaFile` contains exactly one `MainClass` sharing the name with the `JavaFile` itself.
- The `MainClass` extends `JavaClass`, which contains a field `'visibility'` of the type `Visibility`, whose value can be `'public'`, `'protected'`, `'default'`, or `'private'`.

Although `JavaClass` may have one of the four visibility values, the `MainClass` is restricted to the modifiers `'public'` and `'default'`. Is there a way to represent the fact that only two of the `Visibility`-values are valid in the `MainClass` in UML?

Answer (score 0):

Not really. You are asking for a context information of your model which can be expressed by a meta-constraint. This needs to go the the meta-model (modeling rules) of your model and can be used to implement "something" in your modeling tool to obey that constraint. That "something" could be some integrity check to be run regularly or some JIT code to check the constraint.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response :)
I will then add the constraints as additional information in the UML diagram. I think [OCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Constraint_Language) would be the right way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a specialised enumeration LimitedVisibility that is a specialization of Visibility containing only public and default values.
As MainClass is a specialization of JavaClass, you can redefine the attribute visibility and show that its typed with LimitedVisibility.

Your MainClass visibility attribute will look like that:

```
visibility:LimitedVisibility {redefines visibility}
```

The semantics showing that the Feature (e.g. Attribute) is redefinable is shown in Figure 9.9. in UML specification (it is a subclass of RedefinableElement) and details on that in Figure 9.10. Semantics is described in section 9.5.3, details on the notation is provided in 9.5.4 section and example in 9.5.5, especially in figure 9.11.